# Modifying header encoding in a WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, character-encoding

I'm using a Data-Grid control to display informations retrieved from a database.

the Date-Grid is in a window and in this window's constructor i send a Data-Table, then assign the Data-Table view model to the Data-Grid ItemsSource. Every thing is working fine.

**code to get the Data-Table :**

```
public static DataTable GetOrdersDetails(int argOrderId)
    {
        try
        {
            DatabaseRelay.DatabaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(DatabaseRelay.ConnectionString);
            DatabaseRelay.DatabaseConnection.Open();
            DatabaseRelay.DatabaseCommand = new MySqlCommand();
            DatabaseRelay.DatabaseCommand.CommandText =
                "SELECT name, reference, color, photo, description, unitprice AS Prix_Unité, unitsinstock, unitsincommand, contractDate, quantity, totalPrice, comments " +
                "FROM buys b JOIN orders o ON o.OrderId = @argorderid JOIN products p ON p.ProductId=b.products_ProductId";
            DatabaseRelay.DatabaseCommand.Connection = DatabaseRelay.DatabaseConnection;
            DatabaseRelay.DatabaseCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@argorderid", argOrderId);


            DataTable toReturnDataTable = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(DatabaseRelay.DatabaseCommand);
            adapter.Fill(toReturnDataTable);


            return toReturnDataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(DatabaseRelay.DatabaseConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                DatabaseRelay.DatabaseConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

In the CommandText string, notice the unitprice AS Prix_Unité, for me it will make the DataGrid display the header in french language. But when executing the header of this column displays something like this:

[image: Preview]

i tried changing the Data-Grid font family, even the application culture but i can't figure out how to display this header properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the AS Prix_Unité from your select statement then modify the header in the AutoGeneratingColumn event instead

```
Private Sub Data-Grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs)

if e.property = "unitprice" then
    e.column.header = "Prix_Unité"
end if

end sub
```

Comment: this a solution but the window will get maybe 10 different collection with 10 property in each one, i can't do 100 if statement, it's hard.

Comment: if you need to change the column header of more than one field/property of a datagrid then just uses a select case instead of an if.  Its not much more code than hard coding an as ColumnName in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to adjust the FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty using this:

```
 FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```